# Probability of X

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

There can be only 2 possibilities either X or Y. If X occurs first then prob.of X occurring next is 0.4, and if Y occurs 1st prob. of Y occurs next is 0.3. So if X occurs at 5th instant what is the prob. that x will occur at 7th instant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think $0.6\times0.7+0.4\times0.4=0.58$

Comment: note: $X \to Y$ (that is not X$=prob~0.6$) $\to X$(That is not $Y=prob~0.7$) and  $X \to X \to X$ easy.